# In Access, how does one create a new record based on failed search Criteria?

Tags: ms-access

My main question is if I am searching for a Record in Access, is there a way to make it so that if my search does not find a record, that I can be prompted to make a new record based off that search Criteria?

For instance, if I was searching for a last name Burge to make sure Burge wasn't in my record and I found out it isn't, to then have Access prompt me if I want to create a record based on that name?

As of right now, I am just using the search button that is in Access. I haven't done anything to it.

Comment: There must be half a dozen ways to do this, including DoCmd.OpenForm with a where statement.

Comment: I am just using the basic search button that comes in access. I've done nothing special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you will need to override this 'search' bar and implement your own. Put your own unbound text control in the header (or footer) portion of your form. Next, disable navigation buttons to force the user to use your controls. In the after update event for your textbox that you're using to search, you will set your Form.Filter property to your text box control. Like

```
    Me.Filter = "LastName = """ & Me.txtLastFilter & """
```

Then you will check to see if the record wasn't found. By default, the filter will open a new record if the filter criteria is not met. You may then set the new record's Last Name value to your filter boxes value with something like

```
   if me.newrecord = true then
    me.LastName = me.txtlastFilter
```

This is just one of many ways to do this.

Comment: No probs! Of course if you want a 'confirmation' sort of feature, you could use an inputbox or vbYesNo msgbox to allow the user to decide. I would recommend implementing this because of this to prevent dirty data. Without the confirmation, every time someone spells a last name wrong, it creates a new record for "Smth" when you're just trying to get to John Smith's record.